# How to Project Texture onto Specific Surface of a 3D Model in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I am currently working on a Three.js project where I need to project a texture onto a specific surface of a 3D model. I have loaded the 3D model using **GLTFLoader** and have a texture that I want to project onto a specific part of the model's surface. I have attempted to use Raycasting and UV mapping, but I am encountering difficulties in achieving the desired result.

I am specifically looking for guidance from someone on how to accurately project the texture onto a designated area of the 3D model's surface. It would be immensely helpful if someone could provide a step-by-step explanation or a code snippet illustrating the process of projecting a texture onto a specific part of a 3D model in Three.js.

Any advice, examples, or references that can help me accomplish this task would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Examples and illustration of projecting textures in three.js on a specific surface area.

Answer (score 0):

The two common options you might use here in three.js are (1) UV unwrapping, and (2) decals. UV unwrapping is usually done in a visual modeling tool like Blender, then exported to a format like glTF that three.js can load. Any YouTube tutorial for "UV unwrapping in Blender" should explain how to do this method better than a written answer here.

Alternatively, decals may be projected onto the surface without the need for changing UVs. You can see an example, the code used to create it, and documentation on the three.js website:

- https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_decals
- https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/geometries/DecalGeometry

Comment: Thank you so much Don McCurdy, I found your answer helpful and it saved my time. I appreciate that.